# ActionScript Face Detection

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, image-processing, face-detection, edge-detection

I'm looking to get the edges of user's head when the user is in front of a web-cam. I tried googling but to no avail. Can someone point me to some **ActionScript** examples for the same ?

Peace \m/

Answer (score 0):

you can use this ANE from Marpies to check face detection with adobe Air
[face-detection](https://marpies.com/works/face-detection/)